# Breeze Grouping REST Resources

Tags: rest, breeze

Excuse the incorrect terminology on this one....

So, we are heavily using breeze in our application to work with our REST resources, and for the most part is fine.

However, we are typically using the following pattern as a standard:
**/entity/{entityId}/anotherEntity/{anotherEntityId}/andAnotherEntity**

Defining everything in meta data, we use navigation properties and foreign keys to bind this altogether, and works beautifully. We also extend the Breeze Labs Abstract REST DataServiceAdapter in our application.

But, we are now thinking, that to keep the API in a cleaner shape, we may want to 'group' some of the resources into more logical places.

This would then mean the pattern would look something like:
**/entity/{entityId}/entitySpecificGrouping/anotherEntity/{anotherEntityId}/andAnotherEntity**

So, my questions here:

1. Should we even try and do this? Is it RESTful?
2. How do we go about this in Breeze meta data?

I appreciate any input on this matter.